# Image doesn't exist after I "theme it"

Tags: media

Trying to theme image for the first time. Both file and image_style '200x200' exist. In page source code I see this url: http://sitename.com/sites/default/files/styles/220x220/public/guides_images/CBrQ9m1WAAA1EQf.jpg?itok=lGfz-IbP

But second image doesn't exist same as "220x220" folder. What did I miss and how to make image appear(be created by drupal in this folder)?
"The requested page "/sites/default/files/styles/220x220/public/guides_images/CBrQ9m1WAAA1EQf.jpg?itok=lGfz-IbP" could not be found. "

```
//$g is file number
$f = file_load($g);

$img = theme(
   'image_style',
      array(
        'path' => $f->uri,
        'style_name' => '220x220',
        'alt' => 'Alternate Text',
        'title' => 'Title Text',
      )
);

$form['top'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => $img,
);
```